# Difference between Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId and AppDomain.GetCurrentThreadId()

Tags: c#, multithreading

I am running this code:

```
Parallel.For(0, 8, new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 8 },
    i => {
         Console.WriteLine(i +
             " : Thread ManagedThreadId: " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId +
             " ID: " + AppDomain.GetCurrentThreadId().ToString());
    }
)
```

With output:

```
1 : Thread ManagedThreadId: 10 ID: 9004  
2 : Thread ManagedThreadId:10 ID: 9004  
0 : Thread ManagedThreadId: 7 ID: 12884  
4 : ThreadManagedThreadId: 7 ID: 12884  
5 : Thread ManagedThreadId: 7 ID: 12884

6 : Thread ManagedThreadId: 7 ID: 12884  
7 : Thread ManagedThreadId: 7 ID: 12884  
3 : Thread ManagedThreadId: 10 ID: 9004
```

What is the difference between the two ids?

Comment: Be aware that the `AppDomain.GetCurrentThreadID()` is obsoleted, [as per the most recent documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/nb-no/dotnet/api/system.appdomain.getcurrentthreadid?view=netframework-4.7#System_AppDomain_GetCurrentThreadId).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AppDomain.GetCurrentThreadID vs Thread.ManagedThreadID for Windows API calls?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/772354/appdomain-getcurrentthreadid-vs-thread-managedthreadid-for-windows-api-calls)

Comment: See also https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/862bfc35-de8e-4bcc-a56d-e07b3dbbbb37/appdomaingetcurrentthreadid-depreciated?forum=netfxbcl

Answer (score 2):

`AppDomain.GetCurrentThreadId()` is obsolete:

'`AppDomain.GetCurrentThreadId` has been deprecated because it does not provide a stable Id when managed threads are running on fibers (aka lightweight threads). To get a stable identifier for a managed thread, use the `ManagedThreadId` property on `Thread`.

http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=14202'